# Handling http authenticated urls from elisp

Tags: elisp, redirect, http-authentication

is there a library in elisp which helps to get data of a page which is only 
reachable through HTTP redirect after authentication? I've just started looking at the URL lib.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something in the [w3m](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/emacs-w3m) package can help?

Answer (score 0):

Though not an elisp package, the wget library is written specifically for this: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/